# Does a planet do any work when it changes trajectory of spacecraft flying near it?

Tags: classical-mechanics, work

Let's say there is a spacecraft flying near a planet. It just flies near without orbiting the planet. Its trajectory changes as a result of planet's gravitational pull.

Does the planet do any work?

Comment: In what reference frame?

Comment: Let's say that the Sun is the reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the spacecraft has a component of motion along the line connecting it with the planet center, work will be done: $dW = \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{x} = |F| |dx| \cos(\alpha)\neq 0$ as long as $\alpha \neq \pi/2$.

The only case where $\vec{F}$ is constantly perpendicular to $d\vec{x}$ (to $\vec{v}$) is in constant distance between them- which means the motion is circular. Only in this case no work will be done.

Note that the **net** work can still vanish, depending on the curve. A simple test would be checking if the velocity changed when the spacecraft is far away. If so, work was done.

Comment: Let me think about the trajectory change a little: the gravity of the planet is deformation of the space-time. Now let's undo this particular deformation. Is it the case that if the spacecraft's trajectory in the space with the planet's deformation undone is a straight line and its speed is constant, then no work was done. Is that correct when one assumes no forces other than gravity of the planet exist?

Comment: Do you mean that the proper acceleration may vanish?
That would also apply to a freely falling object

Comment: But the speed of a freely falling object is not constant, is it?

Comment: The *proper* acceleration vanishes for a freely falling object

Comment: Energy is frame-dependent...

Comment: I see. Haven't known that proper is the keyword and that it means "acceleration measurable by accelerometer." Suppose posting the comment on a discussion site is a better idea.